# Cannot login normally after login loop

Tags: linux-mint, chmod, ecryptfs, loopback, nologin

I recently had a login loop that kept sending me back to the login screen no matter how many times I entered the correct password. I decided to login accessing the terminal directly by pressing cntrl+alt+F1, where I entered my username and password. After doing so, I got the following message:

```
Signature not found in user keyring
Perhaps try the interactive 'encryptfs-mount-private'
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo commando".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

In any case, I could now access the terminal. However, my `/home/<username>` folder didn't have the files that are usually there, there were just the usual folders (Desktop, Downloads, Videos, etc.) and two new files: `README.txt` and `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop`. To access the latter, it asked me for my login passphrase, which I don't remember, if I ever set one.

After looking for info online I launched the command `sudo chmod 777 /home/<username>` and now I can login through the login screen, but the desktop has the default wallpaper and none of the folders I usually have there. The `/home/<username>` folder is just the same, with the two new files and none of the usual ones.

Any idea what is going on and how could I solve it? I'm using Linux mint.

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Note that permissions 777 are wrong for a home folder and will break multiple things including ssh.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your home was encrypted, which needs your (old?) login passphrase to decrypt.

However, you have a problem: *"it asked me for my login passphrase, which I don't remember, if I ever set one."*

Without the last passphrase that eCryptFS knows, or it's master key, your home files are locked.

When you change your login passphrase normally, it's supposed to automatically update the eCryptFS config to use the new login passphrase. Changing the login passphrase the way any sudo user could, without knowing the current passphrase, doesn't update the eCryptFS config, for obvious reasons.